# Sort files into folders by file name according to a spreadsheet of names

Tags: linux, windows, macos, batch, script

I am a teacher and use Canvas-LMS for my course.  The course is broken into smaller groups led by individual teaching assistants, who grade student assignments in their own section.  Canvas only provides an option to download all student submissions to a given assignment.  Downloaded submissions are automatically renamed in a single folder with the format `lastName_firstNameRandomNumber_SubmissionTime.pdf`.

I have another Excel spreadsheet of student's names and their group numbers.

I would like to make some kind of script that can:

1. compare the portion of the file name and the student name in the Excel sheet;
2. find the group number in the Excel sheet and prepend it to the file name `group1_lastName_*.pdf`;
3. sort the renamed submission files into folders such as `group1` and `group2`.

Comment: You've tagged with Linux, Windows, and MacOS.  Can you use any for this?

Comment: [Answered](https://superuser.com/a/1765347/).  You didn't share your data layout in Excel so I had to guess when creating the *Excel Renaming Formula*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three parts to this problem.

1. Generate a new list of filenames
2. Batch updating the existing filenames
3. Separating files into directory by groupname

MS Excel and a program like [Advanced Renamer (AR)](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/) a *"Batch file renaming utility for Windows"* can take care of this.  While I use [AR](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/) based on familiarity, the solution can be adapted to any other similar tool.

##### Generating new filenames

1. [AR](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/) will allow you to generate a list of *existing* filenames from your files.
2. In Excel that list can be transformed using a formula in order to generate your *modified* filename list.

##### Batch update the filenames

1. [AR](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/) will allow you to rename your filenames using the newly created *modified* filename list.

##### Separate directories by groupname

1. Manually:
   You can sort by name in Windows Explorer (which would effectively sort by groupname based on your preferred naming) and manually move the files based on group name to sepperate folders.
2. Programatically:
   You could do it by script using [AR](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/)

---

### Sample Code

##### Excel Renaming Formula

```
=LET( _oldlist, A2:A200, _namelist, C2:C200, _grouplist, D2:D200,
      _name, BYROW(_oldlist, LAMBDA(r, SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(r, FIND("_", r, FIND("_",r)+1)-1),"_",", "))),
      _group, BYROW(_name, LAMBDA(n, INDEX(_grouplist, MATCH(n, _namelist, 0)))),
      "group_"&_group&"_"&_oldlist)
```

<sup>**Excel Renaming Formula** is based on the data table below.</sup>

| Old Filenames | New Filename | namelist | grouplist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acevedo_Mike_8931_2022-11-08 6.10.pdf | group_9_Acevedo_Mike_8931_2022-11-08 6.10.pdf | Mathews, Lamont | 10 |
| Alexander_Kyra_7746_2022-02-01 23.10.pdf | group_1_Alexander_Kyra_7746_2022-02-01 23.10.pdf | Holt, Mary | 7 |
| Alvarez_Wyatt_2136_2022-04-30 19.10.pdf | group_2_Alvarez_Wyatt_2136_2022-04-30 19.10.pdf | Hampton, Jon | 7 |

##### Advanced Renamer Script

```
function(index, item) { 
  var dir = item.name.match(/group_\d+/g);
  item.newPath = item.path + dir;
}
```

<sup>**Advanced Renamer Script** is based on the filename format:   `group_#_<lName>_<fName>_<rndCode>_<timestamp>.pdf`</sup>

---

### Images

**Generate Filenames (1 of 3)**
[image]

**Generate Filenames (2 of 3)**
[image]

**Generate Filenames (3 of 3)**
[image]

**Update Filenames (1 of 1)**
[image]

**Separate by Groupname (1 of 4)**
[image]

**Separate by Groupname (2 of 4)**
[image]

**Separate by Groupname (3 of 4)**
[image]

**Separate by Groupname (4 of 4)**
[image]

Comment: Answer accepted- Never heard of Advanced Renamer, but glad that such thing exists. Thank you for bringing this program to my radar and giving such a good demo.